# Pyparsing -Match literal at start of line ignoring whitespace

Tags: python, pyparsing

Trying to match this

```
create
```

or

```
create
```

but not

```
#  create
```

This doesn't work.

```
(LineStart() + CaselessLiteral('create')).searchString('''
   create
''')
```

Nor does this

```
(LineStart() + White(min=0).suppress() + CaselessLiteral('create')).searchString('''
   create
''')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyparsing's whitespace-skipping is confusing the issue here, and `LineStart()` is a finicky class to work with anyway.

The core issue is that every pyparsing element runs a pre-parse routine, to skip over whitespace and any ignorable expressions (like comments). In your case, `LineStart`'s pre-parse routine is skipping over the leading whitespace! So it is evaluating "is this the start of a line?" not at column 1, but at column 4, where you have the first letter in "create".

You can suppress this whitespace-skipping on your LineStart element by calling `leaveWhitespace` - that is, don't skip over whitespace during the pre-parse function. This would look like:

```
print((LineStart().leaveWhitespace() + CaselessLiteral('create')).searchString('''\
   create
'''))
```

which will print:

```
[['create']]
```